# Getting results from a method called by NSTimer (obj-c)

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

From what I can make out, NSTimer calls your method once despite how many times it repeats meaning you cannot get an updated result from a method?

How would I implement the following using NSTimer?

1) Loop forever using applescript to grab certain window titles

```
- (void) timer {
if (!_timer){

    //Create timer , timer only gets called once and returns once?
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0f
                                               target: self
                                            selector: @selector(getWindowNames:)
                                             userInfo: nil repeats:YES];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:_timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
    }
}
```

2) Using applescript to grab the title windows

```
//Get the names of all running windows
- (void) getWindowNames : (NSTimer*) timer{

NSDictionary *error = nil;

//AppleScript to get all running window titles
appleScriptFindWindows = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:
                                        @"tell application \"System Events\" to get the title of every window of process \"MyProcess\" whose name contains \"Eagle\""];

//Execute and get the result of the OSAScript
result = [appleScriptFindWindows executeAndReturnError:&error];

//Convert to the result to a string
NSString *stringResult = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result];

//I would like to be able to store a comparison variable here such as....
//NSString *previousResult = stringResult

//If (![previousResult isEqualToString: stringResult]) ....
//Call a method or return to do stuff
```

As I am searching every 1s to find new window titles (Who have different identifiers) I need to be able to compare the strings, each time the timer calls getWindowNames, the data is erased (I believe?) so is there something such as a "class" or "global class" variable that is accessible from all methods within my class and keeps the same value I can use for comparisons?

If so or even if not, some help on understanding how to properly structure what I am trying to do will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The method `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` adds the the timer to the run loop implicitly, delete the two `NSRunLoop` lines.

Comment: I tried before its the only way I can get it to run, when I delete them it compiles properly but doesn't call my method before exiting.

Comment: You can store things in properties of self.

Comment: `getWindowNames` vs `getTitleNames` ... unclear which you mean.

Comment: What object is this code in?  Does that object continue to exist for all the time you want to get timer callbacks?

Comment: @Willeke properties was it exactly what I was looking for! thank you.

The actual issue I have now is getting my timer to run as mentioned by vadian , if I remove the 2 lines it just doesn't work, and to call my timer method I simply calling from main.

    Table *WindowClass = [[Window alloc]init];
    
    [windowClass timer];